# Large number of forms on page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm using ASP.NET MVC to create a web application and have stumbled upon a situation where I'm not sure what the best solution would be.

I have a users page where I am simply loading a list of users and their roles into a table. The roles are checkboxes, for example Manager and Administrator are two separate roles that are expressed as checkboxes on that row for the user.

In the far right column is an Actions field with 3 buttons: Save, Change Password and Delete.

Change Password works by opening a dialog box and hitting an action on the Controller called ChangePassword, this is a Post request as the form is in a different area and some values are set to hidden fields using JavaScript.

Delete works by calling an action called Delete which is a Get request where in the view the action parameters are explicitly set by using the values from the Model. Since these values aren't going to change I can safely do something like this:

```
@Url.Action("Delete", new { loginName = Model.Users[i].LoginName, username = Model.Users[i].Username })
```

However, the Save action is different because the save action is meant to be used to update the user roles, which the user can change by selecting different checkboxes. My initial plan was to make the Save action a Get request and have the values passed in similar to how I do this with Delete but I would need to set some sort of hidden field using JavaScript so that I know which fields are updated.

An alternative solution would be to have every table row a form and make Save a Post action and have the values from the checkboxes bound to the model on the action. I'm not sure whether this would be advised because this could potentially mean 50+ forms on the page depending on how many users I have.

I'd appreciate some advice on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't the built-in membership provider within ASP.NEt an option?

Answer (score 0):

1. [A **GET** request should **never** change the state of your application](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server), i.e. it shouldn't delete or modify users.
2. I'd use the **ASP.Net Membership Provider** and call its respective methods in the Controller Actions.